# How to fix discord.py not sending an embed?

Tags: discord.py

I have been creating a discord.py bot and have run into the issue of my discord bot not being able to send embeds there are no errors in the console the command was working before:

```py
@client.command()
async def usercheck(ctx, username, number):
    collection.update_one({"_id":ctx.guild.id},{"$set": {f'Userid{number}': username}}) 
    for x in collection.find():
        if x["_id"] == ctx.guild.id:
            variable = x["Pop"]
            variable2 = x[f'Userid{number}']
    response = requests.get('https://api.battlemetrics.com/players/' + variable2 + '?fields[server]=name&filter[servers]=' + variable + '&include=server')
    pass_times = response.json()
    Player_id = pass_times['data']['attributes']['id']
    Player_name = pass_times['data']['attributes']['name']
    Server_name = pass_times['included'][0]['attributes']['name']
    Player_online = pass_times['included'][0]['meta']['online']
    Player_id = str(Player_id)
    url = 'https://www.battlemetrics.com/players/' + Player_id
    embed = discord.Embed(title=Player_name, description=url, color=0x1eff00)
    embed.add_field(name="Status", value="Online: " + Player_online, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Server", value=Server_name, inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: what's wrong with the code? any errors?

Comment: If it worked before and it isn't working now, make sure your bot is not spamming the discord API, it might be that the send message never gets awaited because your bot is being rate limited.

Comment: All the other commands are working just not this one so i dont think my bot is being rate limited @NuKeFluffy

Comment: Have you tried printing the response from the battemetrics API too?

Comment: Yes i have printed the data out it just wont send the embed.

Comment: Does the bot have permissions to send and read messages in the channel and are you sure you're sending the command correctly with the correct arguments?

Comment: It is using the correct arguments and has permissions to send messages and read them I don't understand why it won't send a message maybe a fault in my code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226390/discussion-between-nuke-fluffy-and-master-0ogway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this line: `Player_online = pass_times['included'][0]['meta']['online']` returns a boolean, you need to cast it to a string to send messages, this should fix your error:

```
embed.add_field(name="Status", value="Online: " + str(Player_online), inline=False)
```

or:

```
Player_online = str(pass_times['included'][0]['meta']['online'])
```